# lan not working after reboot

Tags: 14.04, networking, lan, wired

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my new notebook and I've got a problem with internet connectivity. When I boot the computer, everything works perfectly fine, but after rebooting using the button in the top right corner (eg after a kernel update), wired internet just doesn't work anymore. There's no problem with wireless, though (however, I mainly use LAN). It can't be a hardware problem, because it works on Windows (it is a dual-boot machine). Mysteriously enough, everything works perfectly if I just plug the notebook in before rebooting - even if I reboot on battery (-> broken) and then one more time on AC (-> fixed again).

I've been doing some further testing: nothing changes if I cut the connection (physically, in the network manager or both) prior to rebooting. `sudo service networking restart` also has no effect with the output

```
stop: Job failed while stopping 
start: Job is already running: networking
```

However, `sudo service network-manager restart` kills the connection in the same way as a reboot, forcing me to shut the computer down and then do a coldboot to get it operational again, but again only when the notebook is running on battery.

I've been thinking_

What could be the cause of that behaviour?

Further command outputs:

`lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2`:

```
05:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

on LAN (working or not) as well as on wireless (to be expected, I just wanted to make sure).

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:62:66:b5:0f:78  
      inet addr:192.168.1.112  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a62:66ff:feb5:f78/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:9907 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6660 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:9730805 (9.7 MB)  TX bytes:726284 (726.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2391 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2391 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:228361 (228.3 KB)  TX bytes:228361 (228.3 KB)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: What kind of notebook? Do you have an exact model type?

Comment: @Pilot6: I've added the output along with some other information - especially worth noting: the problem only occurs when running on battery

Comment: @meskobalazs: it is an Asus N551JX-CN156H

Comment: Can you add the output to `ifconfig` to your question and then drop me a note @Fabby?

Comment: @Fabby: I've added it now

Comment: Could you try with `sudo ethtool --change eth0 speed 10 duplex half autoneg off` and see what that does?

Comment: @Fabby: I was able to solve the problem - it had nothing to do with ethernet-configuration per se but with power-saving settings (hinted at by the battery/ac-difference) and wake-on-lan; I'll submit a proper answer later on. Thanks anyway for your efforts :)

Comment: That was going to be my second iteration (I'm old-fashioned and start bottom-to -top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem: because of the battery/ac-situation, I looked at the power-saving settings in `powertop` and noticed that plugging the notebook in toggled the wake-on-lan-setting.

Anyway, by trial-and-error I figured out that LAN works after both rebooting and `sudo service network-manager restart` if wake-on-lan is activated (I've no idea as to why since I was just lucky enough to stumble over it - I'd be happy if anyone could offer any insight). Therefore, my solution was to add

```
sleep 1
sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g
```

to `rc.local` (the value for sleep might be machine-dependant - I've replaced the HDD that came with the computer with an SSD, so for other machines it might have to be higher; the trick is that the command must be executed **after** the network interfaces have been configured). This way, wol is always activated, regardless of the power state - but with one exception: if you boot the computer on ac and pull the plug some time later, it reverts to the off-state. Normally, this shouldn't be too much of an issue, as you'd have to restart the network-manager via the command line to notice it - and if that really is necessary, a reboot might also be a good idea. Nevertheless, this behaviour can also be fixed by adding a small script to `/etc/pm/power.d/` (similar to the one in the first answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138098/how-to-make-my-screen-brightness-not-change-when-i-plug-my-laptop-in)): in the battery-mode-branch, you put

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g
```

and the ac-mode-branch stays empty.